# Is it a bad idea to hg update when your working copy has changes?

Tags: mercurial

Seems like it would be better if you did commit followed by merge. I'm a little surprised update'ing is even allowed when your working copy has changes. Is allowing updates in such cases to avoid having commits that have two parents, which result from a merge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mercurial encourages recording all the history of a project. If you've done some work in your working directory, why not to commit these changes providing a meaningful description of your results as a commit message and then merge your results into the main branch? It will be more clear for other people to see in two separate changesets what you have made as your *normal work* and what you have made just for *resolving merge conflicts*.

Usually an extra merge changeset is OK, but sometimes you just want to rebase your current changes on top of the main branch before committing them. You might take a look at the **rebase** extension. The new `hg rebase` command allows you to rebase already committed changeses.

Comment: its plausible that support for rebase and other extensions is why hg doesn't enforce this. you can always enforce it yourself by using the defaults section in your hgrc to add -c to hg up

Comment: I like your point about separating your "normal" changes from conflict resolving changes into two commits. I think this is what I was thinking about subconsciously when I thought about how updating with uncommitted changes was a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

I believe [`hg update`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#update) will try to merge your uncommitted changes:

> The following rules apply when the working directory contains uncommitted changes:
>
> 1. If neither `-c/--check` nor `-C/--clean` is specified, and:
>      if the requested changeset is an ancestor or descendant of the working directory's parent, the uncommitted changes are merged into the requested changeset and the merged result is left uncommitted.
>      If the requested changeset is not an ancestor or descendant (that is, it is on another branch), the update is aborted and the uncommitted changes are preserved.
> 2. With the `-c/--check` option, the update is aborted and the uncommitted changes are preserved.
> 3. With the `-C/--clean` option, uncommitted changes are discarded and the working directory is updated to the requested changeset.

That will avoid an unnecessary commit (registered in the `.hg` repo) for an operation (hg update) which only is about updating your **working directory**.

Comment: In the first case, will a hg merge tool be used for merging uncommited changes into the changeset you are updating to?

Comment: I've just tested it. Yes, it does use a merge tool in that case, very nice.